# Docker is reusing the same volume for different containers

Tags: postgresql, docker

I've created two different custom images based on the same official postgres image. The Dockerfile for both looks like:

```
FROM postgres:latest

LABEL vendor="***" \
      vendor.website="***" \
      description="The postgres database"

COPY init.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

These images are used in different docker-compose.yml files. The problem is that the containers based on these images mount the same volume and I end up having the same database for different applications. I thought docker would created separate volumes for different containers. What am I doing wrong?

The docker inspect info:

1. Container 1:

   "Id": "b6ce892e88e08b410af2603041789641cdfe9648e5c36d66d0cff8c495de2720",
   "Image": "sha256:4c6ac32f355cdc93251256cc8e8171fc02bb85d719f4efb9ac6bb999ad66b3ab",
   ...
   "Mounts": [
       {
           "Type": "volume",
                   "Name": "5bb91515eb853e0c18e396b041058d4a03424dfb45c3eb2d2b9890e0b044b461",
                   "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/5bb91515eb853e0c18e396b041058d4a03424dfb45c3eb2d2b9890e0b044b461/_data",
                   "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                   "Driver": "local",
                   "Mode": "rw",
                   "RW": true,
                   "Propagation": ""
       }
   ],
2. Container 2

   "Id": "8c1c9891c462d8520ab107901c39b62fbef389e4501979065a6edb218a25c16a",
   "Image": "sha256:4c6ac32f355cdc93251256cc8e8171fc02bb85d719f4efb9ac6bb999ad66b3ab",
   ...
   "Mounts": [
   {
   "Type": "volume",
   "Name": "5bb91515eb853e0c18e396b041058d4a03424dfb45c3eb2d2b9890e0b044b461",
   "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/5bb91515eb853e0c18e396b041058d4a03424dfb45c3eb2d2b9890e0b044b461/_data",
   "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
   "Driver": "local",
   "Mode": "rw",
   "RW": true,
   "Propagation": ""
   }
   ],

So as you can see the containers based on different images (`4c6ac32f355cdc93251256cc8e8171fc02bb85d719f4efb9ac6bb999ad66b3ab` and `4c6ac32f355cdc93251256cc8e8171fc02bb85d719f4efb9ac6bb999ad66b3ab`) use the same volume `5bb91515eb853e0c18e396b041058d4a03424dfb45c3eb2d2b9890e0b044b461`. I obviously need them to use separate volumes.

**UPDATE 1**

I made the following things:

1. Added different labels to the images so that their hashes would differ
2. Removed the "shared" volume. I mean that one which both containers picked up
3. Started docker-compose up for both apps in turn (without docker-compose down). They shared the volume again.

**UPDATE 2**

1. I removed all the volumes and images on my machine and rebuilt the images for both apps
2. Executed docker-compose down
3. Executed docker-compose up for both in turn (with docker-compose down when switching over the apps)
4. They don't share a volume anymore. Both custom postgres containers use their own volumes.

I'm confused. When different containers share a volume and and how to avoid it?

Comment: Hm, I actually have just noticed that the IDs of the images used match.